# Why does tensordot/reshape not agree with kron?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, tensor

If I define a array `X` with shape `(2, 2)`:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

and take the kronecker product, then reshape the output using

```
np.kron(X, X).reshape((2, 2, 2, 2))
```

I get a resulting matrix:

```
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 2,  4]],

        [[ 3,  4],
         [ 6,  8]]],


       [[[ 3,  6],
         [ 4,  8]],

        [[ 9, 12],
         [12, 16]]]])
```

However, when I use `np.tensordot(X, X, axes=0)` the following matrix is output

```
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 3,  4]],

        [[ 2,  4],
         [ 6,  8]]],


       [[[ 3,  6],
         [ 9, 12]],

        [[ 4,  8],
         [12, 16]]]])
```

which is different from the first output. Why is this the case? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717686/numpy-tensor-kronecker-product-of-matrices-coming-out-shuffled) while searching for answers, however I don't understand why that solution works or how to generalise to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

My first question is, why do you expect them to be same?

Let's do the `kron` without reshaping:

```
In [403]: X = np.array([[1, 2],
     ...:               [3, 4]])
     ...:               
In [404]: np.kron(X,X)
Out[404]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  2,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  4,  8],
       [ 9, 12, 12, 16]])
```

It's easy to visualize the action.

```
[X*1, X*2
 X*3, X*4]
```

`tensordot` normally is thought of as a generalization of `np.dot`, able to handle more complex situations than the common matrix product (i.e. sum of products on one or more axes).  But here there's no summing.

```
In [405]: np.tensordot(X,X, axes=0)
Out[405]: 
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 3,  4]],

        [[ 2,  4],
         [ 6,  8]]],


       [[[ 3,  6],
         [ 9, 12]],

        [[ 4,  8],
         [12, 16]]]])
```

When `axes` is an integer rather than a tuple, the action is a little tricky to understand.  The docs say:

```
``axes = 0`` : tensor product :math:`a\otimes b`
```

I just tried to explain what is happening when `axes` is a scalar (it's not trivial)
[How does numpy.tensordot function works step-by-step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989572/how-does-numpy-tensordot-function-works-step-by-step)

Specifying `axes=0` is equivalent to providing this tuple:

```
np.tensordot(X,X, axes=([],[]))
```

In any case it's evident from the output that this tensordot is producing the same numbers - but the layout is different from the `kron`.

I can replicate the `kron` layout with

```
In [424]: np.tensordot(X,X,axes=0).transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
Out[424]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  2,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  4,  8],
       [ 9, 12, 12, 16]])
```

That is I swap the middle 2 axes.

And omitting the reshape, I get the same (2,2,2,2) you get from `kron`:

```
np.tensordot(X,X,axes=0).transpose(0,2,1,3)
```

---

I like the explicitness of `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ij,kl->ijkl',X,X)    # = tensordot(X,X,0)
np.einsum('ij,kl->ikjl',X,X)    # = kron(X,X).reshape(2,2,2,2)
```

Or using broadcasting, the 2 products are:

```
X[:,:,None,None]*X[None,None,:,:]   # tensordot 0
X[:,None,:,None]*X[None,:,None,:]   # kron
```